# I am not able to stop setInterval() after the if conditions satisfies even after using clearInterval

Tags: angular, setinterval, clearinterval

I am having trouble at running setInterval function. I want this setInterval Function to stop after the if condition satisfies to stop. To do so I have put stopper as the id to setInterval and put clearInterval to end the setInterval. I assure you that this.statusFunc is running well. All I want is that after this.statusFunc gets converted to 1 , which it is , the setInterval() ends.

```
    statusFunc = 0;

    ngOnInit() {

    var stopper = setInterval(function(){
    if (this.statusFunc == 1) {
        console.log(this.statusFunc);
        this.afterFirstSignal();
        clearInterval(stopper);
    }
  }, 2000);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` will not be what you think it should be when your setInterval() handler function is called, so `this.statusFunc` will likely be `undefined`. In order to use the value of `this` corresponding to your component (which I assume is what you want), you have a few options, the cleanest of which is probably to use the arrow operator:

```
var stopper = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.statusFunc == 1) {
        console.log(this.statusFunc);
        this.afterFirstSignal();
        clearInterval(stopper);
    }
}, 2000);
```

The fat arrow operator will preserve the `this` context.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the desired functionality in a potentially more readable way, with

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        skipWhile(() => this.statusFunc !== 1)
    ).subscribe(() => {
        console.log(this.statusFunc);
        this.afterFirstSignal();
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.timer.unsubscribe();
}
```

Or, you could use [an RxJS BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject#behaviorsubject) instead, which can be done without a timer at all. Instead of `this.statusFunc = 1`, you could do `this.status.next(1)`

```
statusSubject = new BehaviorSubject(0);

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.statusSubject.pipe(
        filter(status => status === 1)
    ).subscribe(() => {
        this.afterFirstSignal();
    );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```